# ExtJS standardSubmit doesn't work after Sencha Build

Tags: extjs

The following form submit doesn't work after I perform the Sencha Build on my application. I am trying to download an XLS file using this. I am using ExtJs 4.2.2.

This is the error that I get : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined

```
    var expForm = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
        method : 'POST',
        standardSubmit : true
    });     
    expForm.submit({
            url : 'MyUrl',
            params : {
                xId : 123
            }
    });
```

However when I use ext-all-dev.js for DEV environment. This works fine. Please Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works in Dev, doesn't work in Production usually mean that there are "Synchronous Loading" warnings in development so the build is then incomplete. The rule is to fix all these warnings during development.

Do you get any console errors/warnings either in Dev or Prod?

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much for sparing your invaluable time for this. I am still stuck with this. There are warnings for synchronous loading in DEV but on PROD Sencha build is managing thing well in collating all the required JS files but "standardSubmit : true" is the only configuration that is causing the problem. May be it is because this way it does a standard HTML form submit. Please guide me if you have some answer to this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Well, you **have to** fix synchronous warnings before build. If for nothing else then for eliminating possible reasons.

Comment: Thanks Saki. You were right!.. I use ext-all-dev.js on DEV so it never appeared as any problem. Also the Sencha build could pick and consolidate most of the files but for this, there was no significant KEYWORD e.g. xtype, uses, create, define etc using which the required class could be part of the build process. The following required statement fixed the issue.

Comment: `requires:[
'Ext.form.action.StandardSubmit'
]`

Comment: @Jagpreet Thanks so much for this, it resolved my issue as well. I wish the error was more clear, I would have been stuck on this forever.